# Angular 12 - is not assignable to type '[number, number]

Tags: angular, ngx-charts, angular12

I am trying out ngx-charts library in Angular 12 and I keep getting this issue:

> Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
>
> Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

I don't know what the error means.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```html
<ngx-charts-linear-gauge 
  [view]="view" 
  [scheme]="colorScheme" 
  [value]="value" 
  [previousValue]="previousValue" 
  (select)="onSelect($event)" 
  [units]="units"
>
</ngx-charts-linear-gauge>
```

ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  single: any[];
  view: any[] = [400, 400];
  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#aae3f5']
  };
  value: number = 43;
  previousValue: number = 70;
  units: string = 'counts';

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

Any ideas on what the error means, how to fix this?

ts config code is:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing type definition for view to `view: number[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the issue is the type of you `view` property. According to the docs it must be of type `number[]`: [doc-ref](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/linear-gauge-chart)
note: the type in the docs is not exact enough. `view` is not defined as array of number (`number[]`), but as a tuple of 2 numbers (`[number, number]`) - [source-code ref](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/6a58d9f2d2a2f6f90ad8bc4a1b33087ee65dfeb0/projects/swimlane/ngx-charts/src/lib/common/base-chart.component.ts#L30)

But you define it as `any[]`.
Depending on your typescript compiler settings, you may get an error or warning.

The explict type would be:

```js
view: [number, number] = [400, 400];
```

See more examples and details in this [Stackblitz example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcFMGd1AzA9gJwFygBbnAB2qkWAQwGMBrRAN0mXgBtEB3AOhMQFtgBHAVxnACWiAHbRgANgAcAJgCckgMyyArMCLCA5jzpFkAWgCM0vQOh7hicHqLRoAjcKIAjOpD3hE7gJ443wnuxONOYBQcgSMvLK0soAULGucJQCkIzoANr%20gTQANKBZYQC6ANzxIKA80JCg6qCQAB44dAJw4D7VsWyirTxNkBkFufmhNIWgALyg6QZ50iWxyakTEL2upbHlbb7QJMgCOHA0yCjousigphfC8DSQACYQiJhE1BDtw9nI6YWdIrA1yHOk2ms3mi0YyzO62AACoYbFQDC3ttdvtDoCTqAuv9GAI6HRQOwiGRquAMKTVtVkJAiHcRHQvHknDwkikIZc7pB4AJhPcatAaqBGHtwM5XCs%20giYcBft0Ja4AEo0unCBnLEGgOb8rF-cClcHLcCUpW0%20leaFwqUVOyaGrCLxXWDK0CIeB2rzfIUoMjQJksi4CixwalsdjsSDCTl3JmQEhESrVLyIHigBhVCDk5FuEjk8jQKUy7FwdReADCutO9vVM01YLZkPt5e6FvhiKF5OE1p5GndeUY1TjndIJAEnOEgiI%20IdOBsArORAdLUg7AFrvdWYLsv%20JabsAAksJKJPR5WHcCAOQGc95fz4utLSY73UHo-NO7FIA)

Comment: For some strange reason view = [400, 400]; still gives me the same error? It's very strange

Comment: Editor is complaining about this: [view]="view"   ... the ts file now has this: view = [400, 400];

Comment: you should add the exact error-output and in which line it occurs

Comment: The exact error is: Error: src/app/app.component.html:5:14 - error TS2322: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[number, number]'.
  Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.

5             [view]="view"

Comment: Maybe ngx-charts is not compatable with Angular 12 ?

Comment: try this: `view = [400, 400] as const;`

Comment: No luck...same problem ... hmmmm ... I might have to use a different chart library :(

Comment: strange - and when you use an explicit type: `view: [number, number] = [400, 400];`

Comment: BTW: which version of the lib are you using?

Comment: Sould be the latest ... "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^18.0.1",

Comment: in 18.0.1 view is defined as `[number, number]` [source-ref](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/0bcbb1ca1814adf4664def7b184471de78c3c94a/projects/swimlane/ngx-charts/src/lib/common/base-chart.component.ts#L30) - so the code in my last 2 comments should work. you may post your tsconfig.json - maybe you have some strange settings there.

Comment: I've added the tsconfig code to the question

Comment: You must add the code to your question - not to the answer.

Comment: Anyway, here's a stackblitz example that seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-linear-gauge-chart-qvhmrr?file=tsconfig.json

Comment: Maybe you use  a different type-script version -check your package.json

Comment: I've tried version 16.0.0 of the library and I get the same error ... must be an Angular 12 thing .. I'll look into another charts library for angular

Comment: As [400, 400]' is 'readonly' const cannot be assigned to the mutable type '[number, number]. const can be removed.

Comment: @Guarav Shrestha thanks for the comment, you are absolutely right. I've updated my answer and provided a Stackblitz example.

Answer (score 1):

Set `"strictTemplates": false` in your tsconfig.json, like this:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
   "strictInjectionParameters": true,
   "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
   "strictTemplates": false,
 }
```

Refs:  [Angular Compiler Options](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options)     [TypeScript Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration)